# how to send data through the body in curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl

how to send data through the body in curl, I need to send an array, but somehow the data is not being sent.
I am sending the data from the cero.php and it should be taken in the post cURL method.
I'm printing the param variable with var_dum() to see that the data is arriving, but it still doesn't send it

```
 static public function post($url, $param, $cookie='', 
  $header=array(), $timeout=10)
   {
   
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    @curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
    
    if ($cookie!='') {
        curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    }
    if (count($header)>0) {
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    } 
    
    $body=curl_exec($curl_handle);
     var_dump($param);
    $error=curl_error($curl_handle);
    $head=curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    $cookie=@curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST);
    $status_code=curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
    $str_cookie=self::cookieToString($cookie);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return array('body'=>$body, 'head'=>$head, 'cookie'=>$str_cookie, 'error'=>$error, 
    'status' => $status_code);


}
```

this is my page cero.php

```
  public function subirResolucion()
{

    
    $filter = [
        'sistema' => $this->getSistema(),
        'id_documento' => $this->getIdDocumento(),
        'transparencia' => $this->getTransparencia(),
        'archivo' => $this->getArchivo(),  
    ];

    $url = $this->getUri();
   
    SysLogger::info("Request URI", print_r($url, true));

    $header = [ 
        
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Token ".$this->auth->getToken(),
        "Cookie: ".$this->auth->getCookie()
    ];

    
   
   $param  = array('data'=>json_encode($filter));
    
     $response = Page::post($url,$param,'', $header);
  
   

   $body = json_decode($response['body']);
 

    
   return $body;
   

}
```

this is the answer

what I show with vard_dump

```
   array(0) {
   }
   array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(198574)
    "    {"sistema":"erp","id_documento":"19836601","transparencia":"true","archivo":"JVBERi0xLjQKJdPr6eEKMSAwIG9iago8PC9DcmVhdG9yIChNb3ppbGxhLzUuMCBcKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuM....."}
```

in a photo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o63Sk.png)

This is the response of the system where I send the data

```
{"mensaje":"parameters are missing","estado":false}
```

This is the documentation that they left me with cURL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kficg.png)

Comment: One thing that's suspicious to me is that your var_dump shows the `data` value starting with 4 spaces: `string(198574) "    {` when JSON shouldn't begin with any whitespace. That may cause JSON parsing on the other end to fail.

Comment: add a photo to show the answer

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` value must be a string, but your are passing an array. You can try `http_build_query($param)`

Comment: I tried it that way but it throws me the error that the parameters are not being passed
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($param));

Comment: I recently faced a similar problem and this is how I solved it. Of course, this is about what the other party expects from you, but I just want you to ask yourself a question whether it can be this way. The other party wanted me to keep the json file on my server and give them the url of the file I kept in the body and they read it from there. By the way, you can send the request with Postman and get the code from there.